# How to generate Markov Chain in C#

Tags: c#, data-structures, adjacency-list

I want to create this Markov Chain in C#. I need to know if there is any other structure other than adjacency list which can work better in this situation. Also how can I use the existing .Net collection type to implement this.

[image]

Comment: If you're interested in doing this yourself in C#, you should take a look at https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=745 and the two articles that follow it. They show how to build Markov models in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) is really good general purpose graph library.  It has some implementations for walking Markov Chains.  I recommend checking out the source code.