# Simplifying for-if messes with better structure?

Tags: python, markov-chains

*Please, move this question to [Code Review -area](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It is better suited there because I know the code below is junk and I want critical feedback to complete rewrite. I am pretty much reinventing the wheel.*

```
# Description: you are given a bitwise pattern and a string
# you need to find the number of times the pattern matches in the string.
# The pattern is determined by markov chain.
# For simplicity, suppose the ones and zeros as unbiased coin flipping
# that stops as it hits the pattern, below.
#
# Any one liner or simple pythonic solution?

import random

def matchIt(yourString, yourPattern):
        """find the number of times yourPattern occurs in yourString"""

        count = 0
        matchTimes = 0

        # How can you simplify the for-if structures?
        # THIS IS AN EXAMPLE HOW NOT TO DO IT, hence Code-Smell-label
        # please, read clarifications in [Update]

        for coin in yourString:
            #return to base
            if  count == len(pattern):
                    matchTimes = matchTimes + 1
                    count = 0

            #special case to return to 2, there could be more this type of conditions
            #so this type of if-conditionals are screaming for a havoc
            if count == 2 and pattern[count] == 1:
                    count = count - 1

            #the work horse
            #it could be simpler by breaking the intial string of lenght 'l'
            #to blocks of pattern-length, the number of them is 'l - len(pattern)-1'
            if coin == pattern[count]:
                    count=count+1

        average = len(yourString)/matchTimes

        return [average, matchTimes]



# Generates the list
myString =[]
for x in range(10000):
    myString= myString + [int(random.random()*2)]

pattern = [1,0,0]
result = matchIt(myString, pattern)

print("The sample had "+str(result[1])+" matches and its size was "+str(len(myString))+".\n" +
        "So it took "+str(result[0])+" steps in average.\n" +
        "RESULT: "+str([a for a in "FAILURE" if result[0] != 8]))


# Sample Output
# 
# The sample had 1656 matches and its size was 10000.
# So it took 6 steps in average.
# RESULT: ['F', 'A', 'I', 'L', 'U', 'R', 'E']
```

**[Update]**

I will explain here a bit about theory, perhaps, the problem can be simplified that way. The above code try to construct the markov chain with transition matrix `A` below. The pattern `100` that you can imagine as coin flipping corresponds to it.

```
>>> Q=numpy.matrix('0.5 0.5 0; 0 0.5 0.5; 0 0.5 0')     
>>> I=numpy.identity(3)
>>> I
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> Q
matrix([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ]])
>>> A=numpy.matrix('0.5 0.5 0 0; 0 0.5 0.5 0; 0 0.5 0 0.5; 0 0 0 1')
>>> A
matrix([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0.5,  0. ,  0.5],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ]])
```

The `average` `8` in the question becomes the sum of values on the first row in the matrix `N=(I-Q)^-1` where `Q` above.

```
>>> (I-Q)**-1
matrix([[ 2.,  4.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  4.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  2.,  2.]])
>>> numpy.sum(((I-Q)**-1)[0])
8.0
```

Now, you can probably see that this apparently-only-pattern-matching-problem becomes a markov chain. I cannot see a reason why you could not substitute the messy for-while-if conditions with something similar to matrices or matrices. I don't know how to implement them but iterators could be a way to go, researching, particularly with more states where you need to decompose.

But a problem emerged with Numpy, what are the things `-Inf` and `NaN` for? Check the values to which they should converge, above, from `(I-Q)**-1` matrix. The `N` is from `N=I+Q+Q^2+Q^3+...=\frac{I-Q^{n}}{I-Q}`.

```
>>> (I-Q**99)/(I-Q)
matrix([[  2.00000000e+00,   1.80853571e-09,             -Inf],
        [             NaN,   2.00000000e+00,   6.90799171e-10],
        [             NaN,   6.90799171e-10,   1.00000000e+00]])
>>> (I-Q**10)/(I-Q)
matrix([[ 1.99804688,  0.27929688,        -Inf],
        [        NaN,  1.82617188,  0.10742188],
        [        NaN,  0.10742188,  0.96679688]])
```

Comment: Is this a homework or interview assignment? If so, please tag it as homework.

Comment: Also, the use of triple-quoted strings as comments is atrocious. They should be true comments (i.e., prefixed with `#`).

Comment: gotgenes: no, it is me doing something else than math. This problem could be killed with better structure.

Comment: Using a single triple-quotes string as a comment would at least make some sense. But this way, you're wasting 4 or 5 characters!

Comment: Docstrings should be put _inside_ the function, not outside it.

Comment: Could you post sample input and sample output?  Also, you are using `myString` in your function, but that's an argument to the function.

Comment: There's a comment saying "special case to return to 2" associated with  the following code `if count == 2 and pattern[count] == 1`. What's so special about that case?

Comment: martineau: nothing to me but tried to point it out that this kind of conditionals can become tricky with if-for-structures. Really give me a second and I have solved this myself with some maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - a standard(-ish) string search:

```
def matchIt(needle, haystack):
    """
    @param needle:   string, text to seek
    @param haystack: string, text to search in

    Return number of times needle is found in haystack,
        allowing overlapping instances.

    Example: matchIt('abab','ababababab') -> 4
    """
    lastSeenAt = -1
    timesSeen = 0
    while True:
        nextSeen = haystack.find(needle, lastSeenAt+1)
        if nextSeen==-1:
            return timesSeen
        else:
            lastSeenAt = nextSeen
            timesSeen += 1
```

but you want to do this to a list of numbers? No problem; we just need to make a list class with a find() method, like so:

```
import itertools
class FindableList(list):
    def find(self, sub, start=None, end=None):
        """
        @param sub: list, pattern to look for in self

        @param start: int, first possible start-of-list
            If not specified, start at first item

        @param: end: int, last+1 possible start-of-list
            If not specified, end such that entire self is searched

        Returns;
            Starting offset if a match is found, else -1
        """
        if start is None or start < 0:
            start = 0

        # N.B. If end is allowed to be too high,
        # zip() will silently truncate the list comparison
        # and you will probably get extra spurious matches.
        lastEnd = len(self) - len(sub) + 1
        if end is None or end > lastEnd:
            end = lastEnd

        rng = xrange if xrange else range
        iz  = itertools.izip
        isl = itertools.islice

        for pos in rng(start, end):
            if all(a==b for a,b in iz(sub, isl(self, pos, end))):
                return pos

        # no match found
        return -1
```

then the example looks like

```
matchIt([1,2,1,2], FindableList([1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2])) -> 4
```

and your code becomes:

```
# Generate a list
randIn = lambda x: int(x*random.random())
myString =[randIn(2) for i in range(10000)]

pattern = [1,0,0]
result = matchIt(pattern, myString)

print("The sample had {0} matches and its size was {1}.\n".format(result, len(myString)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def matchIt(yourString, yourPattern):
        """find the number of times yourPattern occurs in yourString"""
```

Are you allowed to use the following?

```
yourString.count(yourPattern)
```

In your case you could create `myString` as a real string of 10000 characters and the `pattern` also as a string and then count the occurence in a simple pythonic way.

**EDIT**

A one-liner that gives you the number of (overlapping) occurences of `pattern` in `text` (which can be either a string or a list), could look like this:

```
nbOccurences = sum(1 for i in xrange(len(text)-len(pattern)) if text[i:i+len(pattern)] == pattern)
```

Comment: N.B. That gives non-overlapping occurences, i.e. `"abababcd".count("abab")` gives 1. That may or may not be what the poster is after, it's really quite hard to tell.

Comment: The definition of the M.C. will infer overlapping occurences, so yes I want overlapping occurrences as well.

Comment: @HH - I have edited my answer to include overlapping occurences as well...

Answer (score 0):

*This is not ready.*

*Similar question but main focus on graph libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606516/python-graph-library) and similar question but in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781907/how-to-generate-markov-chain-in-c), maybe useful.*

The files that are relevant to this question are `./networkx/generators/degree_seq.py` (997 lines, about generating graps with given degree sequence) and `./networkx/algorithms/mixing.py (line 20, function degree_assortativity(G) about probability based graphs)` and also note that its source code refer to 92 references, not sure whether you want to reinvent the wheel. For igraph, please, read the line 835 of the file `convert.c` about weighted edges. You can get the source for [Networkx here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx) and the source for [igraph here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-igraph#downloads). Please, note that the former is under BSD license and done in Python while igraph under GNU (GPL) and done in C.

To get started with Networkx, a helpful line about creating weighted graph from its jUnits `test_convert_scipy.py` -file:

```
def create_weighted(self, G): 
    g = cycle_graph(4)
    e = g.edges()
    source = [u for u,v in e]
    dest = [v for u,v in e]
    weight = [s+10 for s in source]
    ex = zip(source, dest, weight)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(ex)
    return G
```

So to create your Markov Chain, help about directed weighted graph [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#directed-graphs), something like this perhaps:

```
>>> DG=nx.DiGraph()
>>> DG.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,0,0.5),(1,1,0.5),(3,3,1),(0,1,0.5),(1,2,0.5),(2,3,0.5), (2,1,0.5)])
```

or perhaps there is some ready markov chain generation tool as there are for some other stochastic processes, more [here](http://networkx.lanl.gov/tutorial/tutorial.html#graph-generators-and-graph-operations). Cannot find an [algorithm](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.html) to analyze the graph with excepted value or do trials with different sets as in your example, perhaps there is none, and you must stick with other repliers' solutions.